# How can I combine this into a one-liner -- bash

Tags: linux, bash, shell

So I want to recursively search a directory with thousands of folders for a specific file extension and get the date it was added then filter by a specific year.  The code below works but is there a way it can be converted to a one-liner?

1. get all files ending with xml & write to tmp.txt

   ```
   find . -name "*xml" >> tmp.txt
   ```
2. get permission info & timestamp info for all those files in tmp.txt

   ```
   foreach i ( ` cat tmp.txt ` )
   ls -ltrh $i >> tmp2.txt
   end
   ```
3. column 8 contains dates as years, so get all files with years greater than a specific 2014...

   ```
   awk '$8 >=2014' tmp2.txt >> tmp3.txt
   ```

Comment: Why do you need a one-liner if you have things working??

Comment: intellectual curiosity ;)

Comment: Is this Bash? The loop looks more like csh, no?

Comment: are you sure that column only contains years?

Comment: honestly I'm very new so I'm not sure.  When I do ` lsb_release -a` the distro is CentOS? Linux is an OS & bash is the language used to interact with the OS? Excuse my ignorance.

And yes the column contains timestamps too if it was added in the last day but for these purposes the data I'm filtering is historical. I'd probably have to do something else if  that was the case?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this one:

```
find . -type f -name '*xml' -newermt "2014-01-01" -ls
```

From `man find`:

```
   -newerXY reference
          Succeeds if timestamp X of the file being considered is newer
          than timestamp Y of the file reference.   The letters X and Y
          can be any of the following letters:

          a   The access time of the file reference
          B   The birth time of the file reference
          c   The inode status change time of reference
          m   The modification time of the file reference
          t   reference is interpreted directly as a time
```

Comment: The way the output of the file is formatted isn't in my control and is space delimited...

    `Nov    11    2017`

Comment: You can replace `-ls` by something more sophisticated like `-exec ls -lh {} +` or `-printf` where you can pass format parameters to `ls`.

Answer (score 1):

What I would do in a [bash](/questions/tagged/bash) shell :

```
find . -mtime -$((365*4)) -name "*xml" >> tmp.txt
```

This is just an example, adapt the math to your needs...

Another solution :

```
find . -name '*xml' -printf '%TY %p\n' | awk '$1 >= 2014 {$1=""; print}'
```